# Unix mkdir: owner always set as root?

Tags: linux, unix, centos7

I'm logged in on the terminal with my admin account "user1". Whenever I use the `sudo mkdir` command, the directory defaults to owner **root:root**, when I would expect the owner to be **user1:user1**. So every time I create a directory, I have to go back and `chown`, and it's getting tiresome. The account **user1** has its primary group set to **user1**, and is a member of the **wheel** and **www-data** secondary groups.

How can I force the `mkdir` command to set the owner to **user1:user1** instead of **root:root** when creating new directories?

Comment: Should this be migrated to Super User?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t the `mkdir` command, it’s the `sudo` command. It means “run what I say as the root user (or another user I specify)”. When you run `sudo mkdir foo`, the `sudo` program switches to root and then runs `mkdir foo`. Naturally, when root runs `mkdir`, it creates the directory as root.

If user1 has permission to create directories in the relevant location, just drop the `sudo`. If not, then you will need to `chown` them. If user1 needs to make a lot of directories in the same place, look into [adding ACLs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfacl.1.html) so you don’t need `sudo` here.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought mkdir inherently required elevated privileges to execute.

Comment: Nope; if you have write permission to a directory you can create subdirectories or files (or symlinks, FIFOs, or other sorts of special files) without elevated permissions (as long as the file system isn’t read-only or something).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `sudo` when executing `mkdir`.

Comment: Or write a script that checks for `SUDO_UID` and `SUDO_GID` and calls `chown` for you. Maybe `mkdiru` or something like that.